# Increase space between text and icon in dash checklist

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I can adjust the margin and padding around/between various `dcc` components. But I'm aiming to increase the space within these functions. I have a `Checklist` and `RadioItems` below.  I want to increase the blank space between the icon and the text. I have hard-coded some space in the bottom rows below, but is there a way to incorporate this into the `ClassName` or `style` parameters?

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets,suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([html.Label('Item', style={'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                 dcc.Checklist(
                     id='Cats',
                     options=[
                         {'label': 't', 'value': 't'},
                         {'label': 'y', 'value': 'y'},
                         {'label': 'f', 'value': 'f'},
                         {'label': 'j', 'value': 'j'},
                         {'label': 'k', 'value': 'k'},
                         {'label': ' s', 'value': ' s'},
                     ],
                     value=['t', 'y', 'f', 'j', 'k', ' s'],
                     labelStyle = {'display': 'block'},
                     style = { "overflow":"auto", 'margin-right': '50px'}
                 ),

                 html.Label('Type', style={'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                 dcc.RadioItems(['A', 'B', ' C'], 'Scatter',
                            inline=True),
                 ], width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(dcc.Graph())
        ], width=5),
    ],
    className = "four columns vstack gap-2 h-75",
    style = {'padding':'2rem'}
    )
], fluid=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8051)
```

Intended output: I've hard-coded intended space in the final item for both the checklist and radioitem. I'm hoping to pass a function that will do this.

[image]

Edit 2: Uneven text length:

```
values = ['t', 'y', 'f', 'j', 'k', ' s']
options = []

radio_values = ['Aa','Bbbbb','Ccc']
radio_options = []

for i in values: 
    options.append({'label': html.Div(i, style={"display": "inline-block", 'font-size': 15, 'padding-left': "0.5rem"}), 'value': i})

for i in radio_values: 
    radio_options.append({'label': html.Div(i,style={"display": "inline", "padding-left":"0.5rem"}),'value': i})

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([html.Label('Item', style={'display': 'inline'}),
                 dcc.Checklist(
                     id='Cats',
                     options=options,
                     value=values,
                     labelStyle = {"width":"3rem"},
                     style = {'display': 'flex'}
                 ),

                 html.Label('Type', style={}),
                 dcc.RadioItems(radio_options,'A', labelStyle= {"width":"3rem"}, style = {'display': 'flex'}),
             ], width=5),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(dcc.Graph())
        ], width=5),
    ],
    className = "four columns vstack gap-2 h-75",
    style = {'padding':'2rem'}
    )
], fluid=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8051)
```

Comment: The answer is updated according to your last comment

Comment: What if the text doesn't have the same length? E.g edit 2.

Comment: I replaced the `width` property with`margin`, then the width does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html.Div as a lebal and style as you prefer, something like below:

```
{'label': html.Div(i, style={'font-size': 15, 'padding-left': 10}), 'value': i}
```

Also, you need to change the label style to `flex`:

```
labelStyle = {'display': 'flex'}
```

I optimized the code a little below:

```
values = ['t', 'y', 'f', 'j', 'k', ' s']
options = []

radio_options = []

radio_values = ['A','B','C']

for i in values: 
    options.append({'label': html.Div(i, style={'font-size': 15, 'padding-left': "0.5rem"}), 'value': i})
    
for i in radio_values: 
    radio_options.append({'label': html.Div(i,style={"display": "inline", "padding-left":"0.5rem"}),'value': i})

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([html.Label('Item', style={'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                 dcc.Checklist(
                     id='Cats',
                     options=options,
                     value=values,
                     labelStyle = {'display': 'flex'},
                 ),

                 html.Label('Type', style={'paddingTop': '3rem'}),
                 dcc.RadioItems(radio_options,'A', labelStyle= {"margin":"1rem"},style = {'display': 'flex'}),
                 ], width=5),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(dcc.Graph())
        ], width=5),
    ],
    className = "four columns vstack gap-2 h-75",
    style = {'padding':'2rem'}
    )
], fluid=True)
```

**Output:**

[image]

*Please feel free to change the padding as you would.*

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to keep it in block? The RadioItems don't have a space either.

Comment: @Chopin you mean that you need to add vertical space between RadioItems?

Comment: Yes. I've put an intended output in. The final items (`s` in checklist and `c` in radio items) have the intended space.